# WPF ElementHost fails to paint with doublebuffering enabled

Tags: wpf, winforms, double-buffering

Hi I am experiencing a similiar problem to this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/470846/winforms-wpf-interop-wpf-content-fails-to-paint).

Whats different for me is that I am using in my WinForms-MainForm the "CreateParams-Method" to force doublebuffering. Code for this is (following e.g. [DataGridView draws wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5859826/createparams-solved-flickering-but-datagridview-draws-wrong)):

```
protected override CreateParams CreateParams
{
    get
    {
        // Activate double buffering at the form level.  All child controls will be double buffered as well.
        CreateParams cp = base.CreateParams;
        cp.ExStyle |= 0x02000000;   // WS_EX_COMPOSITED
        return cp;
    }
}
```

My problem is now, as long as this CreateParams is activated, the content of my WPF-ElementHost in a WinForms-Usercontrol are only drawn when there is a mouseover event.

Short description: The UserControl "opens" but it's transparent. After I move over it with my mouse, e.g. the ComboBoxes get drawn.

As soon as I comment out the CreateParams everything works just fine (with the WPF-ElementHost). Is it possible to just deactivate / use different CreateParams for the WPFElementHost?

Comment: Did you ever solve this problem? I'm experiencing the same issue.

Comment: @TormodFjeldskår: Nej. I never found a way to solve this. I just commented out the CreateParams-Section for the whole Application. Did you?

Comment: No, unfortunately not. Removed the CreateParams code from the form and added it to only those screens that do not host WPF controls.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the [render mode](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4951250/1102585) on the WPF control worked for me:

```
private void Control_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    HwndSource hwndSource = PresentationSource.FromVisual(this) as HwndSource;
    HwndTarget hwndTarget = hwndSource.CompositionTarget;
    hwndTarget.RenderMode = RenderMode.SoftwareOnly;
}
```

Comment: I can't reproduce this anymore, it's been a while.. ..so sorry for not accepting your answer :/

Comment: Actually, I found later that this answer has a problem related to graphics drivers and will cause the entire system to crash on some computers http://stackoverflow.com/q/17473857/1102585 , it works fine for most but 1 out of 5 machines I tested crashed with this solution